# Getting error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper in Spring Boot test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

When I try to run my Spring Boot test, I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.mapper.Mapper
```

This seems to be due to some conflicts from gradle but I can't figure out what's causing it.

The dependencies:

http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IIVEX . 
(It's too long to paste here)

The gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public" }
}

dependencies {

    compile(group: 'com.testcompany', name: 'util-lib', version: "1.0.1", classifier: 'lite')

    //Testing
    testCompile(group: 'com.testcompany', name: 'util-testing', version: "1.0.1", classifier: 'lite')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
}
```

Comment: That class belongs to the `tomcat-util` lib, seems you are missing it in your dependencies as it's not listed in the dependency tree...

Comment: @araknoid When I add it as version "8.5.11", I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.ExceptionUtils.preload()V`. Oddly, if I up it to "8.5.16" (which matches what spring boot 1.5.6 uses for tomcat), then I get the original error about the Mapper class.